# How to call a function after all setTimeout functions is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

How to call the second function after the all previous functions is done.

```
function first() {
    // code here
    setTimeout( function() {
        // code here
    }, 1000);

    // code here
    setTimeout( function() {
        // code here
    }, 3000);

    // code here
    setTimeout( function() {
        // code here
    }, 3800);
}

function second() {
    // code here
}

first();
first();
second();
first();
second();
```

It seems all functions executed in the same time. 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript Wait until all async calls finish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205266/javascript-wait-until-all-async-calls-finish)

Comment: Basically you need to increase the timeout (milliseconds) on each call, otherwise all of them are being triggered at the same time.

Comment: calling of settimeouts is async. they do not wait for each other

Comment: The functions called depending on conditions, so I don't know the timeout that I need.

Comment: If you need to have `second` function run after `first` async method, you could wrap `first` in a promise and call `second` in the `then` chain when the promise resolves.

Comment: Do you expect those three calls in `first()` to happen in series or parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to call a specific function after the last timeout, I think this will point you in the right direction. Of course, it can be written better, with reusable "class" etc.

```js
function myTimeout(f,t) {
    var p = new Promise(resolve=>{
      setTimeout(()=>{
        resolve(f.apply(this,[]));
    }, t);
    });
    

    //return p.promise(); 
  return p;
}

function first() {
    var numberOfTimeouts = 3
    // code here
    myTimeout(()=>{
        // code here
        console.log('a')
    }, 1000).then(()=>{
      numberOfTimeouts--;
      if (!numberOfTimeouts) second()
    });

    // code here
    myTimeout( function() {
        console.log('b')
    }, 3000).then(()=>{
      numberOfTimeouts--;
      if (!numberOfTimeouts) second()
    });

    // code here
    myTimeout( function() {
       console.log('c')
    }, 3800).then(()=>{
      numberOfTimeouts--;
      if (!numberOfTimeouts) second()
    });
}

function second() {
   console.log('d')
}

first();
```

Comment: If you're going to use Promises, at least use `Promise.all` to synchronise them instead of kludgy counters